Tableau WDC error Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://apex/api" from origin "http://xyz.8888" has been blocked by CORS policy
I am getting this error in browser console when running my JavaScript and jQuery code. Does anyone have this error in past? Any help will be appreciated.
Error:
condition: without any datatype selected

ERROR1: Browser console error: Access to XMLHttpRequest at "https://apex/api" from origin "http://xyz.8888" has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

condition: With datatype set to 'jsonp'

ERROR2: No browser console error but getting no response back. But get this under the chrome browser Network tab for the call to API: (failed) net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_ORB

Updated my ajax call as follows:
Tried setting up datatype to 'jsonp'
Tried setting headers with Access-Control-Allow-Origin to \* 

// Download the data
    myConnector.getData = function(table, doneCallback) {
        console.log("Inside Data download");
*****Works until here, but fail at this ajax call*********
        $.ajax({
                crossDomain: true,
                headers: {'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'},
                dataType: 'jsonp', ====> IF YOU REMOVE DATATYPE IT GIVES ERROR 1 ABOVE WITH DATATYPE IT GIVES ERROR 2
                url: 'https://apex/api',
                success: function(resp){
                    var feat = resp.features,
                    tableData = [];

            // Iterate over the JSON object
            for (var i = 0, len = feat.length; i < len; i++) {
                tableData.push({
                    "id": feat[i].id
                });
            }

            table.appendRows(tableData);
            doneCallback();
        }
        });
    };


This is a security error, indicating that default settings do not allow you to do this.
Access-Control-Allow-Origin is a response header.  It must be set by the server, not you.  It you control the server, you can change these settings.  Otherwise, you can talk to the company that controls the API.
See Cross-Origin Resource Sharing at MDN for more information.
